# Validating EditText with multiple white listed variables

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, onclicklistener

So I have a Validation created for my editText to only allow permission to the next Activity only after a certain set of whitelisted values are enterd in the edittext, Otherwise a Toast appears.

My question is in this line of code

**

> if ( ( zipcode.getText().toString().trim().equals("33314")))

**

How do i list multiple values such as, 33314,33328,33354 as i cannot separate by commas.

This is my Code...

```
    zipbtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.zipbtn);
        zipbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                insertValues();
                EditText zipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);

                if ( ( zipcode.getText().toString().trim().equals("33314")))

                {
                Intent secondpage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(secondpage);
            }

            else {
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: create set of whitelisted strings, and use `set.contains()` method to check if the set contains whatever you want. For example - string entered in the EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the allowed String values in an HashSet like:

```
HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<>();
values.add("11111");
values.add("22222");
```

and then check with

```
if (values.contains(zipcode.getText().toString().trim()))
```